# html2canvas Images with .svg format are not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html2canvas

When we are taking screenshots using html2canvas, images having .svg extention will not render properly. I have tried giving allowTaint:true option, still it is not working.

Code snippet:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="background-image:url('image.svg');">
</div> 

html2canvas($(".myDiv"), { 
allowTaint: true, 
onrendered: function (canvas){
     //use canvas 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Could you please share your code for the community to help.

Comment: <div class="myDiv" style="background-image:url('image.svg');"></div>

html2canvas($(".myDiv"), {
            allowTaint: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas){
                       //use canvas
            }
});

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas will capture background svg image if we used img tag instead of div tag with url in scr attribute. So the solution I found for this is, dynamically creating new img tag for each div before calling html2canvas function.

```
    $(".myDiv").each(function () {
        var url = $(this).css("background-image")
        var src = url.substring(5, url.length - 2);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = $(this).height();
        ctx.canvas.height = $(this).width();
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        $(this).append(canvas);
    });
```

This will work only for cases where you can replace div tag with img tag.